# What rules does the identity element follow in a Ring.

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

I know that an element $e$ is called identity element in a group, say $(R, \cdot)$ if $e$ follows the rule

$$
a\cdot e=e\cdot a=a
$$

for all $a\in R$.

My question is: What rules does $e$ have to follow for it to be considered the identity element of a ring, say $(R,\cdot,+)$.

Comment: You should also assume $e \cdot a = a$ for all $a \in R$.

Comment: In a ring, there is an identity with respect to multiplication (usually denoted with $1$) and one with respect to addition (usually denoted with $0$), and they are never equal. Which one do you mean?

Comment: @Ruben They are equal if and only if the ring is trivial (contains exactly one element).

Comment: Ok, I forgot about the degenerate case, but my point still stands ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ a ring. Then, an element $e \in R$ is said to be a multiplicative identity if $a \cdot e = e \cdot a = a$ for all $a \in R$ (in that case, $(R,+,\cdot)$ is called a unital ring).

Moreover, an element $0_R \in R$ is said to be an [additive identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_identity) if $a + 0_R = 0_R + a = a$ for all $a \in R$.

Answer (score 1):

There are two operations in a ring and thus potentially two identity elements.

- The identity element $0_R$ with respect to addition ($+$) has to fulfill: for all $a \in R$, 
  $$a+0_R= 0_R +a = a$$
  although $a+0_R=a$ would suffice as addition is always commutative.
- The identity element $1_R$ with respect to multiplication ($\cdot $) has to fulfill: for all $a \in R$,
  $$a\cdot 1_R= 1_R \cdot  a = a.$$
  Your definition of a ring may or may not requirer the existence of a multiplicative identity.

The additive and multiplicative  identity are different if (and only if) the ring contains at least two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Well you'd have an identity element for each operation.

If $R$ is a ring, then that means $R$ is an abelian group under addition, so $\exists 0$ such that $a+0=a \space \forall a\in R.$ (We don't need the condition that $0+a=a$ because $R$ is abeliean.

In addition, $R$ is a monoid under multiplication, so $\exists 1$ such that $a \cdot 1=1\cdot a=a \space \forall a \in R.$

So $0$ is the additive identity, while $1$ is the multiplicative identity, so to speak.

However, there's actually a lot of debate in the mathematical society whether a ring should have a multiplicative identity 1. Fraenkel said they did, but Noether disagreed. Recently, most authors require the existence of a multiplicative identity. If you want to be very precise, a ring with a multiplicative identity defined is called a *unitary* ring, whereas a ring without is called a *rng* or *pseudo-ring*.

Comment: There has never been a *debate* about rings having identity in the mathematical community, but there has been different usage.  Real mathematicians know that it is ok for conventions to vary between works, so there is no controversy here. However, there has been plenty of debate among users of websites like math.SE  and Wikipedia about this, for whatever reason, since the users seem to feel, against all reason, that the convention has to be settled once and for all.

Comment: @rschwieb Ah, I guess that is true--"debate" certainly is a strong word to use here. Just wanted to tell the OP that there would be differences depending on which text he uses.